# How to access 'this' variable in a prototype function if it is overridden?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I call set function in my constructor this way, the `this` variable will be overridden, (like I would use `this.set.bind(object,index,element)` somehow)

```
$.each($.parseJSON($selector.val()),this.set);
```

Set is a prototype function:

```
Class.prototype.set = function(item,val){
    //here I would like to get the real this in order to set data
    this.data[item] = val;
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

I have managed it work this way, but I would like to know if any trick exists or not for the first one.

```
var o = $.parseJSON($selector.val();
for(var i in o)
   this.set(i,o[i]); //this works
```

UPDETE:
These also works:

```
$.each($.parseJSON($selector.val()),(function(i,e){this.set(i,e);}).bind(this));
```

or

```
var self = this;
$.each($.parseJSON($selector.val()),function(i,e){self.set(i,e);});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` might be overriden by using `Function.call()` or `Function.apply()`.

To keep original, you need `Function.bind()` either natively or by using some polyfill.

Try this:

```
$.each($.parseJSON($selector.val()),this.set.bind(this));
```

**UPDATE:** What about this approach?

```
var that = this;
$.each($.parseJSON($selector.val()), function() { return that.set.apply( that, arguments ); } );
```

The typical bind() works similar to this:

```
function myBind(func,ctx) {
    return function() {
        return func.apply(ctx,arguments);
    };
}
```

This might be used to simplify second example above, again:

```
$.each($.parseJSON($selector.val()),myBind(this.set, this));
```

Comment: this way does not work either, I think jQuery ignores binded value